# allign cell accessory type to the left of the row swift

Tags: ios, swift, accessorytype

Is there any way to align the cell accessory Type in a swift table to the left rather than the default right aligned accessory type?

I want the chekmark to show on the left side of the row when selected.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. However a work around would be to find an image of the checkmark or similar and set it to `cell.imageView.image` property, which is on the left side of the cell.

Comment: Maybe you can add an accessory of your own, not use the default accessory.